# Outsourcing Grafana's authentication process to my application server

Tags: authentication, grafana

**Background:**

I have an application server that has an endpoint of /api/token. What this API does is it performs authentication against the supplied username and password using the standard basic authentication protocol.

When the process is successful, it returns an access token and HTTP code of 200 (OK). When fails, HTTP code 401 (unauthorised) is returned.

**Question:** Is there any way I can make Grafana's login page to pass on the login credential to my application server for authentication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, unless you want to hack source code.

But you can use Grafana in [auth proxy mode](http://docs.grafana.org/auth/auth-proxy/), where authentication will be made by some "auth" proxy. For example, auth will be made by reverse proxy (e.g. Apache+mod_authnz_external) which will be in front of Grafana. All auth logic will be there and Grafana will just receive the request with request header `X-WEBAUTH-USER` value when user authentication is successful.

Another option is to start OIDC Identity Provider (for example [Keycloak](https://www.keycloak.org/)), which will use your app auth endpoint for authentication. Grafana has native OIDC/OAuth support, so it will be just configured against your OIDC Identity Provider.